# Circular menu with ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

I found this amazing circular menu on codepen. link: https://codepen.io/juslwk/pen/xgbDB.

I wanted to adopt it to reactjs. I am a complete beginner in react. When I tried to copy over the code to try it out first, no circular menu appears. just a bunch of nav list items. Also, for my small side project, I don't need to push a button to make the menu appear as they do in the link. I want the whole menu with the middle button to be there always.So I am not using the JS they have to make it close and open.

I copied over the html code as below and I am using the CSS as is:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props){
     super(props)
  }
  
  render (){
      return (
        <div class="container">
            <div class="component">
              <h2>Hi</h2>
             
              <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button">Menu</button>
              <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <span>Home</span>
                     
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Furniture</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Transport</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Gift</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Clothes</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Games</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Stationary</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Toys</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Books</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Register</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Sell</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: PS: I added the "opened-nav' CSS class they use after the "cn-wrapper" class.

Comment: Because you did not include the javascript from the codepen example so the button does not do anything. And this is quite challenging for beginner, so I would recommend you to study more about css animation if you want to make something like this.

Comment: @wyfy,  I wanted the circular menu present at all times. without using any button to open it up. That is where my problem lies I think.

Comment: If you look in the settings of that example, it uses an external library as well, `cdnjs`, so you would have to include it in your app as well. And in the js file, you see that he is adding dynamic classed to the html so that it has the "opened style" or "closed style" .If you figure those classes out and add them to your components, then it may works

Comment: @John I have worked it out for you, check my answer below. Just run the snippet.

Comment: @MosiaThabo honestly I really dislike the precedent, where user just straight up copy-pastes code from somewhere and you basically do all the work for him/her. At the very least please provide some explanation as to what went wrong in his version - because this just sets a bad example where the new user will be more likely not to put any effort and just post a question hoping somebody will solve it for that sweet sweet karma and on the other hand from your reply he doesn't even have the opportunity to learn and is motivated to simply copy-paste the answer (again).

Comment: Well, I think @John wanted the menu converted into a react component, so he's done a lot in converting the entire html into react. So the problem was getting the menu to behave like it does on codepen after being converted into react. I felt exactly what you are saying but at the end I realized that atleast he's moved the html, so he's just not sure what was wrong... One of the things I found wrong was having the class `csstransforms` which seemed to have been a container on the css from the codepen

Comment: @John don't do what you have done, you will find people who are not going to tolerate that. I just assisted because I had some few minutes to assist. People here want to help others solve real problems... we want to help you improve your code not make code for you! Welcome to React, you are going to find this library exciting and make it your goal to explore it each day... I can assure you that within a month you'll be far.

Comment: @MosiaThabo fair enough, either way, +1 for the effort :)

Comment: Thank You Mate! :) @SamuelHulla

Answer (score 1):

Here's the clone of that sandbox project. If you don't want to toggle the menu using a button, all you need to do is add a class name `opened-nav` to your  `<div className="cn-wrapper opened-nav" id="cn-wrapper">` element. And it should always remain open, if you're chosing to leave it open as default then just remove the state management on the component below.

It is all up to you on what you want to do, but the clone is below:

```js
function MenuComponent() {

  const[menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const wrapper = document.getElementById("cn-wrapper");
  function toggleMenu()
  {
    setMenuOpen(!menuOpen); 
  }
  
  React.useEffect(()=>
  {
    if(wrapper) 
    {
      if(menuOpen)
        wrapper.classList.add("opened-nav");
      else
        wrapper.classList.remove("opened-nav");
    }
  },[menuOpen]);
  
  return (
    <div className="container csstransforms">
      <div className="component">
        <h2>Hi</h2>
        <button className="cn-button" onClick={toggleMenu} id="cn-button">Menu</button>
        <div className="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <span>Home</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Furniture</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Transport</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Gift</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Clothes</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Games</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Stationary</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Toys</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Books</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Register</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Sell</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MenuComponent />,
document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

* { 
  position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #52be7f;
    color: #fff;
}

.component {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    height: 15em;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.component > h2 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12em;
    opacity: 0.1;
    cursor: default;
}

.cn-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 11;
    margin-top: -2.25em;
    margin-left: -2.25em;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 4.5em;
    height: 4.5em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #52be7f;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-top: -13em;
    margin-left: -13.5em;
    width: 27em;
    height: 27em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
    transition: all .3s ease 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*cover to prevent extra space of anchors from being clickable*/
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper:after{
  content:".";
  display:block;
  font-size:2em;
  width:6.2em;
  height:6.2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.1em;
  top:50%;
  margin-top: -3.1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index:10;
  color: transparent;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav {
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    margin-left: -10em;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg); 
    transform: rotate(75deg) skew(62deg); 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
    position: absolute;

    right: -7.25em;
    bottom: -7.25em;
    display: block;
    width: 14.5em;
    height: 14.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #429a67;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
    background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #429a67 35%);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 2;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
    transform: skew(-62deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a span {
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    display: block;
    font-size: .5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
    background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #449e6a 35%);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
    transition: all .3s ease .3s;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:first-child {
    -webkit-transform: skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(62deg);
    transform: skew(62deg); 
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav  li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(150deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg) skew(62deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(210deg) skew(62deg);
}
.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(240deg) skew(62deg);
}
.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(10) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg) skew(62deg);
}
.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(11) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(300deg) skew(62deg);
}
.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(12) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
    transform: rotate(330deg) skew(62deg);
}
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10em auto;
    padding: .5em;
    text-align: center;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    float: left;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 5em;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a{
    background-color: #6F325C;
    color: #fff;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-button {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
    .no-csstransforms li {
        width: 4em;
        height: 4em;
        line-height: 4em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .no-ccstransforms .cn-wrapper {
        padding: .5em;
    }

    .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
        width: 4em;
        height: 4em;
        font-size: .9em;
        line-height: 4em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
        font-size: .68em;
    }

    .cn-button {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:420px) {
    .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3em;
        line-height: 3em;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```